# Creating and logging in a user in RSpec when using Devise_Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, devise-invitable

How can I create a user and log it in when testing with RSpec when using `devise_invitable`? Is it possible to have a user setup and logged in without sending/testing the emailing of the invitation? Is it possible to do this with FactoryGirl?

I am using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting the `invitation_accepted_at` attribute in your factory.  This should bypass devise_invitable when you try to login (or whatever) in your spec.

```
factory :user do
  email
  invitation_accepted_at { Time.zone.now }
  password "secret"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Once I've got the user in my rspec test the invitation_accepted_at attribute is nil in the object as well as in the database.